# Delete entire conversation in Google Groups

Tags: google-groups

Any idea on how do I delete an entire conversation in a Google Group hosted by me?

I am able to delete only individual messages. I can't see a link for deleting the entire conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Google, it can't be done.

> #### [How can I delete an entire topic in my group?](http://groups.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75244)
>
> We don't currently offer a way to delete an entire thread at once. To remove a thread, you'll need to delete each message one by one, which will require that you either authored the posts or own the group. To prevent abuse within groups, only the author or a group owner can delete a given post.
>
> If you're the group owner, follow these steps to remove the posts:
>
> 1. Click the title of the thread in question.
> 2. On each message, click the "more options" link.
> 3. Click the "Remove" link.
> 4. Select "Yes, remove it now" and then click "Confirm."
>
> Once each post in a thread has been deleted, the topic disappears from the Discussions section altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you are looking for, but you can close a topic by going to the group, then the topic, then hitting options, then ticking close this topic. This will stop people from replying to the group about that topic.

Unfortunately, I think it may be impossible to "delete" a topic, as usually it will have been sent to peoples' inboxes, where you can't delete messages.

Comment: mainly i need to delete the conversation, as we have new people joining the group. i dont want them to have access to this particular conversation.